# Raphael JS: Changing circle into a another shape using a path

Tags: javascript, raphael

I currently have created a ball bouncing

```
 var ball = paper.circle(700,275,25,25)
    var a = 50;
    ball.attr({
        fill: "180-black-red"
    });
```

In this function the ball bounces to the top. I then tried to make it change shape by doing ball.animate and the path. But this is not working.

```
function bounce_normal(){



   ball.animate({cy: 220, cx: 275}, 500, 'ease-out' );

     ball.animate({ path: "M190.5,320.5A20,20,0,1,1,190.1,320.5Z"});


}
```

I also tried to remove the cy and cx values however it still doesn't change shape. Is there a way to solve this?

**Update**

I now learnt I need to use a path for by ball.

```
 var ball = paper.path("M190.5,320.5A20,20,0,1,1,190.1,320.5Z")
    var a = 50;
    ball.attr({
        fill: "180-black-red"
    });
```

Is there anyway of learning what that path means so i can animate the pathm ie: making it bounce ?

Comment: Could you put a working example with the issue on a jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4y53wxs0/1/ I have done this , but i don't understand where i can enter my cx cy values so it will go to that point and animate there.

Comment: there is no cx,cy for a path, you just adjust the path points/co-ordinates.